# Java Append object to JSON

Tags: java, json

I would like to append JSON object to existing JSON array to get data structure like this.

```
"results":[
      {
         "lat":"value",
         "lon":"value"
      }, 
      {
         "lat":"value",
         "lon":"value"

      }
    ]
```

I'm trying to do it using the code in example, but unfortunately whole object is overriden everytime.

```
    Log.i(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "POSITIONS AVAILABLE " + jsonDataString);
                AppHelper helper = new AppHelper(ctx);
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
                JSONObject valuesObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
                //putv given values to the JSON
                valuesObject.put("lat", lat.toString());
                valuesObject.put("lon", lon.toString());
                valuesObject.put("city", city);
                valuesObject.put("street", street);
                valuesObject.put("date", helper.getActualDateTime());
                valuesObject.put("time", helper.getActualDateTime());
                list.put(valuesObject);
                //mainObject.put("values", list);
                mainObject.accumulate("values", list);
                saveJsonData(ctx, mainObject.toString(),"positions");
```

How it should be right?

Put and accumulate everytime rewrite all previous values, but i would like to append this object:

```
{
     "lat":"value",
     "lon":"value"
  },
```

Into results parent.

BTW: I would like to do it without GSON.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isnt any problem with your code. It does append

```
String jsonDataString = "{\"results\":[{\"lat\":\"value\",\"lon\":\"value\" }, { \"lat\":\"value\", \"lon\":\"value\"}]}";
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
JSONObject valuesObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
valuesObject.put("lat", "newValue");
valuesObject.put("lon", "newValue");
valuesObject.put("city", "newValue");
valuesObject.put("street", "newValue");
valuesObject.put("date", "newValue");
valuesObject.put("time", "newValue");
list.put(valuesObject);
mainObject.accumulate("values", list);
System.out.println(mainObject);
```

This prints `{"values":[[{"date":"newValue","city":"newValue","street":"newValue","lon":"newValue","time":"newValue","lat":"newValue"}]],"results":[{"lon":"value","lat":"value"},{"lon":"value","lat":"value"}]}`.
Isnt this what you are expecting?

With gson you can do like

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;


public class AddJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"results\":[{\"lat\":\"value\",\"lon\":\"value\" }, { \"lat\":\"value\", \"lon\":\"value\"}]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject inputObj  = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
        JsonObject newObject = new JsonObject() ;
        newObject.addProperty("lat", "newValue");
        newObject.addProperty("lon", "newValue");
        inputObj.get("results").getAsJsonArray().add(newObject);
        System.out.println(inputObj);
    }

}
```

Comment: And without GSON? I wrote that i won't use GSON in this case :)

Comment: Oops sorry.I don't see any issue with your code. Just checking through it. Ideally it should append.

Comment: I'm sorry i make mistake in my own code accumulate is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Approach**

```
    String jsonData = "{\"results\":[{\"lat\":\"value\",\"lon\":\"value\" }]}";
    System.out.println(jsonData);
    try {
        JSONArray result = new JSONObject(jsonData).getJSONArray("results");
        result.getJSONObject(0).put("city","Singapore");
        jsonData = "{\"results\":"+result.toString()+"}";
        System.out.println(jsonData);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**OutPut Before Appending**

```
{"results":[{"lat":"value","lon":"value" }]}
```

**OutPut After Appending**

```
{"results":[{"lon":"value","lat":"value","city":"Singapore"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new value to an Object you can try the below as well

Before:

```
{
    "Name": "EnCoMa",
    "Manager": "Abhishek Kasetty"
 }
```

code :

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();      
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = ow.writeValueAsString(TheObjectToWhichYouWantToAddNewValue);
    ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(json);
    node.putPOJO("new Key","new value")
```

after:

```
{
    "Name": "EnCoMa",
    "Manager": "Abhishek Kasetty",
    "new Key": "new value"
}
```