# How to merge 2 JSON Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json

In example, I have these 2 JSON Objects

```
jsonObject1 = [
             {"id": "1", "name": "name1", "children": [{"id": "2", "name": "name2"}] },
             {"id": "3", "name": "name3", "children": [{"id": "4", "name": "name4"}] }
             ];

jsonObject2 =[
             {"id": "4", "name": "name1", "children": [{"id": "6", "name": "name5"}] },
             {"id": "5", "name": "name3", "children": [{"id": "7", "name": "name6"}] }
             ]
```

How do I merge the 2 JSONObject into 1 **matching on the outer object name** and get this result?

```
mergedJsonObject = jsonObject1.merge(jsonObject2);

mergedJsonObject = [
                    {"id": "1", "name": "name1", "children": [
                                                             {"id": "2", "name": "name2"}, 
                                                             {"id": "6", "name": "name5"}
                                                             ] 
                    },
                    {"id": "3", "name": "name3", "children": [
                                                             {"id": "4", "name": "name4"},
                                                             {"id": "7", "name": "name6"}
                                                             ] 
                    }
                    ];
```

Comment: Is your question about Java or Angular? Please include your attempts at a solution

Comment: I'm doing this in java which i will eventually implement to my angular website using angular 2's tree node.

Comment: Where did JSON id 5 go? It's not clear what your merge conditions are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724221/java-append-object-to-json might also be helpful

Comment: @Ronaldo and these are not object they are arrays of object

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects in question happen to be JSONArrays, why not (pseudocode):

```
  merge (arr1, arr2) {
     for (int i=0; i < arr2.length, i++) {
        JSONObject row = arr2.get(i)
        arr1.add(row)
     }
     return arr1
```

Comment: This doesn't merge the objects with matching names, only adds the arrays all together

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following.

```
for o1 in jsonObject1
    for o2 in jsonObject2
        if o1['name'] == o2['name']
           o1['children'].push(o2['children'])
// inspect jsonObject1
```

<sub>There's probably a better way to do this than a nested loop, but whatever</sub>

And make sure that you aren't inserting an array into the other array, but rather adding all the elements

Comment: I didn't downvote (in fact, I upvoted).  But the OP didn't explicitly say he WANTED to eliminate duplicates...Nevertheless - interesting solution :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Pretty sure "How do I merge the 2 JSONObject into 1" implies that. Am I wrong?